# Server is forcing trailing slash on only one URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching

My .htaccess has a rewrite that removes .php from the URL so that:

`http://example.com/page.php` changes to `http://example.com/page`

This has been working fine for years until I needed to change the name of a file. Now this is happening:

`http://example.com/newpage` changes to `http://example.com/newpage/` and throws a 403 error.

Here's the rewrite that works for everything else:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I'm sure this is some type of caching issue combined with Apache adding a trailing slash by default, but I can't figure out where the caching is happening and I don't want to turn off Apache's trailing slash for security reasons (plus, I shouldn't need to).

Because you'll ask:

1. I'm using a cPanel VPS with Centos 5. Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.
2. cPanel doesn't appear to have a way to clear the Apache cache. htcacheclean wasn't there and I didn't want to install it in case it screwed up something with cPanel.
3. Yes, I cleared by browser cache. Tried a new browser. Tried a new computer.
4. File name is correct. If I change the URL to http://example.com/newpage.php it works fine.
5. It's been four hours since I made the initial change.
6. Tried rebooting server.

Any ideas?

Comment: No folder with the same name?

Comment: Son of a $%@$$%! Yes! That was the problem. I'm not sure who put that folder there, but there wasn't even anything it it. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I was able to help a little.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a trailing slash using `.htaccess` you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

It should fix the error you're experiencing.